# 404 custom error template .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Ok, I have a problem, my .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

and I have not found.html near .htaccess.

Why is it not working? I don't believe what I'm seeing. I took the tutorial from here 
http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/

I just want that every time I access www.site.com/ajfasoijfiajsfijaofij to show what is it in notfound.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using `ErrorDocument` , the file you're specifying is relative to DOCUMENT ROOT not `.htaccess` location!

**Edit:**
assume you have `notfound.html` and you want to use it for folder `dir01`, you create an `htaccess` file inside this folder and add  this:

```
ErrorDocument 404    /dir01/notfound.html
```

If you want to access your file(`notfound.html`) in browser it would be `http://www.example.com/dir01/notfound.html`. that's all I could explain!

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your .htaccess file the following code:

RewriteBase /

Comment: In your .htaccess :
`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html`